# Unable to load Django YAML fixture file

Tags: django

I have a Django project that contains a "list" application. I'm trying to load some user data into the auth_user table using a YAML fixture file.  Each time I run the command, it doesn't display any errors but it also says "Installed 0 objects".  Here's the file:

```
- model: list.auth_user
  pk: 1
  fields:
    is_superuser: false
    username: user1
    is_staff: false
    is_active: true
    date_joined: 2018-07-06
  pk: 2
  fields:
    is_superuser: false
    username: user2
    is_staff: false
    is_active: true
    date_joined: 2018-07-06
```

The file is located in `~/project/list/fixtures/testusers.yml` and I'm running this command:

```
python manage.py loaddata testusers
```

I've tried it by giving model the arguments "list.auth_user" and "auth_user" but neither resolves the problem.  The Django fixture doc doesn't say that any file extension is required when specifying the fixture file.  I'm using Django 1.84 and have PyYAML installed.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have PyYAML installed?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what your file structure is?

Comment: Answers to both questions are contained in my question.

Comment: I don't mean just the location of the testusers file. I mean the file structure of your entire project